# withLatestFrom unexpected behavior

Tags: rxjs

I have an unexpected behavior with the operator withLatestFrom.

Output

```
map a
a
map a <== why a is mapped again ?
map b
b
```

```js
const { Subject, operators } = window.rxjs
const { map, withLatestFrom } = operators


const createA = new Subject()
const createB = new Subject()

const a = createA.pipe(
  map(() => console.log('map a'))
)

const b = createB.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(a),
  map(() => console.log('map b'))
)

a.subscribe(() => { console.log('a') })
b.subscribe(() => { console.log('b') })

createA.next()
createB.next()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't with `withLatestFrom()` but rather with how subscriptions work. Observables are lazy and don't **run** until you subscribe. Each new subscriptions will **run** the observable again.

```
const stream$ = from([1,2,3]);
stream$.subscribe(console.log) // output: 1 2 3
stream$.subscribe(console.log) // output: 1 2 3
```

In this case, `from([1,2,3)] ran twice. If I alter my stream, anything I do will happen for each subscriber.

```
const stream$ = from([1,2,3]).pipe(
  tap(_ => console.log("hi"))
);
stream$.subscribe(console.log) // output: hi 1 hi 2 hi 3
stream$.subscribe(console.log) // output: hi 1 hi 2 hi 3
```

The final piece of the puzzle is this: internally `withLatestFrom()` subscribes to the stream that you give it. Just like an explicit `.subscribe()` **runs** the observable, so does `withLatestFrom()` once it's subscribed to.

You can use `shareReplay` to cache the latest values and replay them instead of running the observable again. It's one way to manage a multicasted stream:

```
const createA = new Subject()
const createB = new Subject()

const a = createA.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('tap a')),
  shareReplay(1)
)

const b = createB.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(a),
  tap(() => console.log('tap b'))
)

a.subscribe(() => { console.log('a') })
b.subscribe(() => { console.log('b') })

createA.next()
createB.next()
```

Now `a.subscribe()` and `withLatestFrom(a)` are both getting a buffered value that only gets **run** when `createA.next()` is executed.

---

As an aside, mapping a value to nothing is bad habit to get into. Consider the following code:

```
from([1,2,3]).pipe(
  map(val => console.log(val))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This will output

```
1
undefined
2
undefined
3
undefined
```

because you're actually mapping each value to nothing. `tap` on the other hand doesn't change the source observable, so it's a much better tool for debugging and/or side effects that don't alter the stream

```
from([1,2,3]).pipe(
  tap(val => console.log(val))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This will output

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the operator `share()` allows multiple subscribers.

```js
const a = createA.pipe(
  map(() => console.log('map a')),
  share()
)
```